# SSH over HTTPS through haproxy

Tags: ssh, haproxy, stunnel

I'm trying to setup an ssh over https connection using haproxy. I haven't found any working examples, so any help would be appreciated!

client config;

```
~$ cat ~/.stunnel/stunnel.conf
pid=
client=yes
foreground=yes
[ssh]
accept=4444
connect=ssh.example.com:443
```

client output;

```
~$ stunnel ~/.stunnel/stunnel.conf 
2014.08.15 10:16:50 LOG5[5454]: stunnel 5.02 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu platform
2014.08.15 10:26:05 LOG5[5598]: s_connect: connected 115.0.0.0:443
2014.08.15 10:26:05 LOG5[5598]: Service [ssh] connected remote server from 10.0.0.0:45343
2014.08.15 10:26:05 LOG5[5598]: Connection closed: 23 byte(s) sent to SSL, 188 byte(s) sent to socket

~$ ssh -v -p 4444 user@localhost
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
```

server config;

```
~$ cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    maxconn 500
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option tcplog
    timeout connect 20s
    timeout client 50s
    timeout server 50s
    timeout tunnel 1h

frontend public
    mode tcp
    bind :443 ssl crt example.pem no-tls-tickets

    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if HTTP

    use_backend ssh if !HTTP
    use_backend ssh if { hdr(host) -i ssh.example.com }
    use_backend btsync if { hdr(host) -i btsync.example.com }

    default_backend nginx

backend nginx
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    server nginx localhost:8001 check

backend btsync
    server btsync localhost:8888 check

backend ssh
    mode tcp
    server ssh localhost:22
    timeout server 2h
```

server output;

```
~$ tail -f /var/log/haproxy.log
Aug 15 16:10:20 localhost haproxy[42548]: 203.0.0.0:52385 [15/Aug/2014:16:10:20.278] public~ nginx/<NOSRV> -1/-1/83 187 PR 0/0/0/0/3 0/0
```

As far as I can tell stunnel isn't actually connecting to the `ssh.example.com` subdomain, it simply does a lookup and connects via ip, thus the route within haproxy is going to the main nginx block ...

Comment: How is "ssh over https" a useful scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it to select the ssh backend by using `ssl_fc_sni` instead of `hdr(host)`

```
use_backend ssh if { ssl_fc_sni ssh.ceaseless.info }
```

Answer (score 4):

I did not manage to use ssl_fc_sni for that, so I used [another method](https://blog.chmd.fr/ssh-over-ssl-episode-4-a-haproxy-based-configuration.html). Basically, it consists in checking if the first packet of the connection starts with the string 'SSH-2.0'. This translates to:

```
acl client_attempts_ssh payload(0,7) -m bin 5353482d322e30
use_backend ssh if !HTTP
use_backend ssh if client_attempts_ssh
```

I hope that somebody finds this useful.

Comment: It keeps refusing to work for me. :]